# Flattening a map with a value of Option[T]

Tags: scala

I have a map that's currently represented in a sequence like `Seq[(String, Option[T])]`. I don't care about the `None` values in the map since I want to do some operations like, say, sorting on them so I can identify which key to use. I can do something like this:

```
val mapping: Seq[(String, Option[Foo])]

mapping.filter(_._2.isDefined)
    .sortBy(_._2.get.someInt)
    .headOption.map(_._1)
```

...but there has to be a better way to write this. In particular, the `get` makes me uncomfortable since the value is still of a type `Option[Foo]`, although there **should** be no `None` values in it.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Seems like you're sorting the entire list to get just a single element. There is `maxBy` for that.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: I'm open to answers that challenge the question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the following definitions for `Foo` and `mapping`:

```
case class Foo(someInt: Int)
val mapping: Seq[(String, Option[Foo])] = Seq(("a", Some(Foo(42))), ("b", None))
```

you have several options:

#### `collect`

The `collect` method combines pattern matching with filtering:

```
mapping.collect{case (s,Some(Foo(i))) => (s,i) }.sortBy(_._2).headOption.map(_._1)
```

---

#### `for`-`yield`

Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect with `for`-`yield`, it will also throw out all the elements that don't match:

```
(for ((s, Some(Foo(n))) <- mapping) yield(s, n)).sortBy(_._2).headOption.map(_._1)
```

---

#### O(N) solution with `minBy`

Also note that sorting the entire collection just to extract the maximum / minimum is unnecessary: there is `maxBy` / `minBy` for that:

```
Option(for ((s, Some(Foo(n))) <- mapping) yield (s, n))
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .map(_.minBy(_._2)._1)
```

Wrapping the entire sequence into `Option` is necessary so we can filter out the case when the sequence is empty, so we don't invoke `minBy` on an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.collect` instead of `.filter`:

```
mapping
  .collect { case (s, Some(t)) => s -> t.someInt }
  .sortBy(_._2)
  .headOption
  .map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `flatten` over a `Seq[Option[_]]`, it will remove all of the `None` and get the values of the `Some`. You're right to feel wary about using `get`, that's generally somewhat unsafe given the (however unlikely) chance of nulls.

```
val mapping: Seq[(String, Option[Foo])] = ...

mapping.flatmap{case (key, maybeValue) => maybeValue.map((key,_))}
  .sortBy(_._2.someInt)
  .headOption.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use use `sortBy` on `Option[Int]` and then clean up unwanted data with `collect`,

```
scala> final case class Foo(someInt: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val data = Seq(("zebra", Some(Foo(26))), 
                      ("banana", Some(Foo(1))), 
                      ("empty", Option.empty[Foo]))
data: Seq[(String, Option[Foo])] = List((zebra,Some(Foo(26))), (banana,Some(Foo(1))), (empty,None))
```

example:

```
scala> data.sortBy(_._2.map(_.someInt))
           .collect { case (k, Some(v)) => k}
           .headOption
res1: Option[String] = Some(banana)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove None elements you can use collect or flatMap instead of filter. And if you want to be more expressive avoid to use _1 or _2 Tuple methods and replace them with a case.

```
case class Foo(someInt: Int)

val list = Seq("1" -> Option(Foo(1)), "2" -> Option(Foo(7)), "3" -> None, "4" -> Option(Foo(-2)))

val r2 = list.flatMap { case (key, foo) => foo.map( key -> _.someInt) }.sortBy { case (_, value) => value }.headOption.map { case (key, _) => key }

val r = list.collect { case (key, Some(foo)) => (key, foo.someInt) }.sortBy { case (_, value) => value}.headOption.map { case (key, _) => key }


println(r)
println(r2)
```